# Tomcat - using SSL on some directories but not on others

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

How can I configure tomcat7 & SSL to only require authentication on selected subfolders of my web site?

For example, I have a folder that I want to be publicly accessible:
/nonSecure/

While I have another folder that requires authentication:
/secureStuff/

What do I need to do? I have a feeling the answer lies in the conf/web.xml or the conf/server.xml files but so far have had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide appropriate `<security-constraint>` entries in your web.xml, that specify `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` for the URLs you want to secure with HTTPS.

Assuming you are using Container Managed Authentication. If you aren't, you should be.